# Dismiss UIAlertView programmatically in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am stuck in a weird scenario where I need to programmatically dismiss the active UIAlertView from the other viewcontroller by getting the instance.

Actually, I am working on AutoClose feature (working on System.Timer) where when Timer would be elapsed, I need to perform some operation (performs in View Model) and close the active UIAlertView or UIViewController window and Navigate To HomeView.

I am able to do with UIViewController but I couldn't find any way to dismiss the UIAlertView which is presented from another view controller?

Note - I understand this API is deprecated but for using UIAlertController it would lead to ample code changes, and I don't have time to make them.

I am using below method to accomplish but once the AlertView gets dismissed I am unable to click anywhere on screen.

```
UIWindow window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
UIViewController rootViewController=window.RootViewController;

if(rootViewController.ModalViewController is UIAlertController)
{
    rootViewController.ModalViewController.DismissViewController(true,null);    
}
```

Also, may I know how do we see the hierarchy of Views in Xamarin Studio?

Comment: Note - I understand this API is deprecated but for using UIAlertController it would lead to ample code changes. So, I would not prefer to do it as of now since it's urgent requirement for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked the same question in Xamarin Forum and I got my answer from one of the Xamarin Professional which I am sharing here.

[Dismiss UIAlertView programmatically in Xamarin.iOS](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/138725/dismiss-uialertview-programmatically-in-xamarin-ios/p1?new=1)

I hope this may help others.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the  following code:

```
UIAlertView alertView = new UIAlertView("Title", "Content",this,"OK");
alertView.Show();

UIActivityIndicatorView indicatorView = new UIActivityIndicatorView();
indicatorView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
indicatorView.Center = new CGPoint(alertView.Bounds.Size.Width / 2, 
alertView.Bounds.Size.Height - 40.0);
indicatorView.StartAnimating();
alertView.InsertSubview(indicatorView,0);
```

And if when you want to Dissmiss the AlertView(for emample in the following code I dissmiss it after 3 seconds):

```
NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(3, (t) =>
        {
            alertView.DismissWithClickedButtonIndex(0, true);
        });
```

Comment: What does  alertView.DismissWithClickedButtonIndex(0, true); does? Currently, I have implemented of getting key window and check if it has UIAlertCotroller as ModalViewCotroller and based on that I DismissModalViewCotroller. Now alert gets dismissed but, I am unable to click else where on screen.

Comment: If the answer is useful ,please mark it as answer so that other developer can so search it easily when they have the similar problem.If you have new problem,you can creat a new question so that I can solve it better.

Comment: LucasZ - I need to dismiss the AlertView from different ViewController not from the same where it was presented. So, I need to get the AlertView instance and than I need to dismiss it.

Comment: Anyone having idea to accomplish this?